# How can I use phone speaker while headphones in

Tags: headphones, speaker

How can I output the audio through the normal phone speaker while plugging my headphones?

I'd searched a lot, but seems to find nothing except [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036221/how-to-turn-speaker-on-off-programatically-in-android-4-0) and it didn't work on Nexus 6 nor Note 3.

Actually I need to use my headphone as mic pnly and the normal phone speaker to output sound.

Comment: Asking as a developer or an end user? Have you tried [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix&hl=en) app?

Comment: Asking as a developer, but I want to verify it works as a user first.

Comment: @Firelord , beeshyams The app doesn't work for me! I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Works fine in my Nexus 6. Can you explain the steps you took with that app? All I did in that app was set *Media audio* to Speaker, connected the headphones, increased the volume since that app muted it and there we go.

Comment: I did the same steps. I'll try another headphone and will get back to you in minutes.

Comment: It doesn't work with me on either headphones. How is that possible? I have marshmalleow. I think you have the same version too.

Comment: I'm using build MMB29Q of Android M. Can you try this app on your Note 3?

Comment: I have do it now it doesn't work at first ,but it does now and returned to my nexus and it works there too. Now. Thanks ;)

Comment: So, could you post an answer mentioning how you made it work somehow?

Comment: There is something weired here though. The mic got that is recording is the one that is built in not the headphones one.

Comment: @Firelord I have write the answer. you might wanna review it.